Globalization of ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application
I have developed an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application with globalization, I've created the role folder structure for Views/Controller/ViewModels .resx for each language.
While debugging running on IIS Express from Visual Studio or accessing it via localhost in the IIS Server the localization is working fine.
But when I try to access it from outside by the hostname, it doesn't change the language. I've searched a lot, added parameters to the web.config, but it didn't work. Could someone give a hand?
This is the program.cs from the application
using FastReport.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using MYAPP;
using MYAPP.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

builder.Configuration
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SncMesSloRpcContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseContext")));
builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IStringLocalizer<>), typeof(StringLocalizer<>));

var app = builder.Build();

var supportedCultures = new[] { "en", "pt", "es" };

var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
    .SetDefaultCulture("es");

localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>()
    {
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider(),
        new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
    };
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}");
    //pattern: "{controller=Dashboards}/{action=Index}");

app.Run();


Have you set up globalization in IIS? If not, please refer to this link to set up globalization in IIS: .NET Globalization.

Yes I did it and checked it again. At the published server accessing it as localhost the localization is working fine. It doesn't work accessing from outside.

I've enabled the https protocol on the IIS server for the site and the localization is working fine. It's not only working on the http. And I need it to work on the http

After many attempts at IIS settings and changes to the program.cs and startup.cs files, I discovered that the problem of the location not working in HTTP, but working in HTTPS, was due to the cookie setting being fixed in the page's login controller. I changed this setting and now it's working. Thanks to those who tried to help, instead of just editing the post to inflate their ego.
Here's the code working:
 Response.Cookies.Append(
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
                    new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), HttpOnly = false, Secure = false, Path = "/" });



app.UseHttpsRedirection();

I found that there is https redirection in your code, so there should not be http.
Please check if you have some other settings that redirect requests to http, which may lose globalization settings in the process.

Not even removing this https redirection it works. If I run from localhost at the IIS server it works fine, If I set it to https it also works (but it's a local app which do not have certification).
